Разница между дампом памяти и образом памяти
Никак не могу найти подробную информацию о том, что такое образ памяти (memory image). Из того что я нашел, сложилось впечатление, что это то же самое, что и дамп памяти. Так ли это? Если нет, подскажите пожалуйста, что это и где можно почитать подробнее.

В целом да, это одно и то же. Но исторически так сложилось, что создание memory dump всё-таки обычно связано с тем, что программа или даже операционная система выполнила недопустимую операцию, после чего она не может продолжать работать и при этом на всякий случай ОС автоматически создаёт образ памяти (то бишь как-раз memory image) процесса/ядра/ОС, чтобы можно было потом при желании в нём покопаться и выяснить, почему же произошла критическая ошибка.
При этом сам по себе термин memory image не ассоциирован с такими катастрофическими событиями и может создаваться, например, для целей отладки программы.
Так что, резюмируя: memory dump - это тоже самое, что memory image, но условия, в которых он автоматически создаётся, связаны с критической ошибкой какого-то процесса или даже ядра операционной системы.
